# Pip error "No matching distribution found for perceptilabs"

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

So I'm trying to install Perceptilabs so I can have a GUI for TensorFlow. I'm following their install instructions, which is `pip install perceptilabs`. However, I keep having the error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement perceptilabs
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for perceptilabs

Here's a screen shot:

[Can't embed images yet, here's the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GvPB.png)

Even when I do `python -m pip install perceptilabs`, `py -m pip install perceptilabs`, `pip3 install perceptilabs`, `python -m pip3 install perceptilabs` or `py pip3 -m install perceptilabs`, it still doesn't work. Even in a virtual env.

I have Python 3.8.3 and 3.9.4 installed, pip and pip3 21.0.1, Tensorflow 2.5.0-rc1, Windows 10 Pro version 20H2 x64, with an Intel Core i5-3470 CPU, 8 GB RAM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

unfortunately it's only supported on python 3.7 and 3.6 for the moment; you can see in the pypi page Requires: Python >=3.6, <3.8

Comment: Thanks, installed Python 3.7, it's working now. 